# localtime giving different results for tm_hour/tm_isdst on Android and Windows

Tags: android, c, windows, datetime

I've noticed that localtime seems to give different results on different platforms, despite the fact that every definition I can find seems to define it the same way.

I run the following code on Windows:

```
struct tm *tm1;
time_t ltime = (time_t)0;
tm1=localtime(&ltime);
```

then edit, recompile and run the following:

```
struct tm *tm1;
time_t ltime = (time_t)60*60*24*30*6;
tm1=localtime(&ltime);
```

The results are the same except for a difference of roughly 6 months and more importantly the following:

```
tm1.tm_hour = 00000000 //epoch
tm1.tm_hour = 00000001 //epoch + 6 months
```

This is expected since epoch (Jan 1st 1970) is not in daylight savings time for my timezone (GMT) but it has entered DST after 6 months. This demonstrates that Windows correctly applies DST rules.

However, when I do the same on Android I get:

```
tm1.tm_hour = 00000001 //epoch
tm1.tm_hour = 00000001 //epoch + 6 months
```

I have no idea why the results aren't consistent, this is surely about as simple as it gets! The only thing I can imagine is that, rather than applying DST rules, it is getting the localtime at epoch=0 for my **current** timezone, BST(GMT+1). Incidentally I've also done this on iOS, OSX and Linux, which also display the same problem as Android.

The clearest definition of localtime [I can find](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zvm/v6r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.zvm.v620.edclv%2Fmktime.htm) seems to suggest that it should work as it does on Windows:

> If an application uses localtime() to determine local time, localtime() will determine if daylight savings applies (assuming DST info is available) and will correctly set the tm_isdst flag.

tm_isdst is also stuck at 0 on the faulty platforms but changes on Windows, as it should.

Some obvious checks out the way:

- Timezone: All devices are currently set to the same timezone
- Hardware clocks: they seem synced but it shouldn't matter as I am passing in my own time value anyway, zero. localtime only requires
  the time value you pass in, the DST rules and the timezone according
  to TZ.

Comment: Note 1) `60*60*24*30*60` overflows on 16-bit `int` (embedded), suggest `60L*60*24*30*60` 2) GMT should not observe DST.

Comment: 1) None of the platforms I'm compiling for are 16-bit. Actually, I don't think I've ever compiled a 16-bit app!
2) I'm not sure what this means to be honest. There **is** a DST version of GMT, it's BST. There's no DST version of UTC, sure, and UTC is the same timezone as GMT, but that doesn't therefore mean GMT never has DST applied.

Comment: Yes, folks can live in an area that observe GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) for a portion of the year and another like BST (British Summer Time) for the summer.  "GMT" refers to a DST-less _time_ identifier - Hence the comment about GMT not observing DST.  Also agree that many folks consider GMT an area (time zone) of UK, Ireland, Portugal, Iceland, etc.  But this _area_ is better describe as [Western European Time time zone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_European_Time) than GMT.  Note: There are slight technical differences between GMT and UTC.

Comment: Well, okay. I don't really get how that relates to my problem. It's not like I'm setting TZ to GMT myself, and the device isn't returning GMT right now either. If anything the problem is that localtime on non-Windows platforms fails to recognise that Epoch, which is GMT, is non-DST.

Comment: Did you try to use `localtime_s` instead of `localtime`? `localtime` returns a pointer to the singletone structure, so the both results points to the same memory